# WiX is installing shortcuts to C:\Users\Public when it should not

Tags: windows-7, directory, wix, windows-installer, user-accounts

WiX is installing a shortcut that I've created to ***C:\Users\Public\Desktop***.  The problem is:  I don't specify that directory.  At all.  Anywhere.  It's the wrong User account.

Where I *want* to install the shortcut to is ***C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop***  (this account will always exist on any target machine).

I've tried various ways to hardcode the destination.  Here are some of them:

Using the `<SetDirectory/>` element.

```
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ADMIN"/>
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                    ...
                <Directory Id="MyProductDir"  Name="MyProduct"/>
 </Directory>

 <SetDirectory  Id="ADMIN" Value="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"/>




 <Component Id="Cmp_MyProduct" Guid="..." Directory="MyProductDir>
      <File Source="MyProduct.exe"/>
 </Component>

 <Component Id="Cmp_AdminDesktop" Guid="..." Directory="MyProductDir">
       <Shortcut Id="Shortcut_Admin" Name="MyProduct.exe"
                 Directory="ADMIN"  Target="[MyProductDir]MyProduct.exe"/>
       <RemoveFolder Id="Admin_RemoveFolder" Directory="ADMIN" 
                     On="Uninstall"/>
       <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" .... KeyPath="Yes"/>
 </Component>




 <Feature Id="Install_MyProduct" Level="1">
       <ComponentRef Id=Cmp_MyProduct"/>
 </Feature>

 <Feature Id="Install_to_Desktop" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="Cmp_AdminDesktop"/>
 </Feature>
```

I also have tried not using the `<SetDirectory/>` element and just created the ***C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop*** directory the normal way (nesting `<Directory/>` elements).

And I've tried a zillion other things, and it KEEPS installing the shortcut to ***C:\Users\Public\Desktop***!

Is there a Public thing that I'm missing?

The Log files show that it's installing to the ***C:\Users\Public\Desktop*** file, but it doesn't seem to give a good reason why.  It does show that the value of the `<SetDirectory/>` element is ***C:Users\Administrator\Desktop***, for what that's worth.

Has anyone else ever had a problem with WiX installing to the wrong User?

Comment: Why don't you use the pre-defined property `<Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368276(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @BrianSutherland, `DesktopFolder` specifies the path of the desktop folder for the *current* user, but he wants to create a shortcut for the specific user `Administrator`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Directory` attribute from the `Shortcut` element and setting `<Component Directory="ADMIN" ... >` instead? Also, `HKCU` for the keypath registry key seems wrong as that would tie the keypath to the *current* user instead of the `Administrator` user.

Comment: The reason I can't used the pre-defined property <Directory  Id="DesktopFolder"/> is because it won't install to the C: drive when I do that.  See, WiX installs to the writable drive with the most space.  On my test machine, it's the D: drive.  I've tried setting the ROOTDRIVE property to C:, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Also, the "DesktopFolder" property installs to the desktop of the user that's logged in.  For simplicity's sake, I left a lot out of my explanation.  I'm having to install various things to various places dependent on the accounts that exist on the machine (Administrator admin account might be called something else).

Comment: @zett42, I have not tried doing those things to the shortcuts.  You may be on to something!

Comment: @zett42, All of my textbooks say to use the HKCU root.  Of course, textbooks can't account for all of the weird situations.  I'm not sure how to deal with this.  Can I use HKLM?